# Create a post with custom taxonomy and custom field using raw MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to insert multiple posts using just raw MySQL with the following:

1. Check if post duplicated by `post_name` field or not and IGNORE inserting if so.
2. I need to insert a custom taxonomy called `newspaper` for the post.
3. Create custom fields with the new post I already registered and I have the keys `fifu_image_url`, `fifu_image_alt`, and `_cmb_link`

I'm not SQL expert so I just did the basic query like so:

```sql
INSERT INTO `ctapp_posts`(`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`)
VALUES ?
```

Comment: Do you have to use raw SQL? WP has inbuilt functions to help with this and make it much easier than trying to create all the multiple entries yourself.

Comment: Yes, it could be WordPress!

Answer (score 0):

This won't throw errors, and won't insert if duplicate.

1. `INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_posts (post_name)-> VALUES(' . $postName . ')`
2. A bit more tricky. But you can read about the relations here: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy
3. You can log into the database and create new columns in wp_posts. Just set them to default *null*. This won't disturb the rest.